# Xcode archiving succeeds but doesn't show up in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a new version of my app using Xcode 7 and even renamed the project. Now, when I'm trying to archive, the process succeeds, but the archive doesn't show up in organizer. When I restore my previous version and then try to archive it (also with Xcode 7), everything works fine and the archive shows up in Organizer, so that I think that anything has changed in the new version that causes the error to occur - eventually the project rename.

When I look after the archive in Finder, it is shown, but when I'm trying to open it, I get the following error message:

> The archive could not be installed. The archive may be corrupt or unreadable.

[image]

I've already followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html) official Apple documentation, but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Any idea, how I can successfully archive my app, so that it shows up in Organizer?

BTW: My app consists of an iOS app, a today extension and a watchOS 2 app.

Comment: I think rename mess up many things, I was never able to rename project using xcode without any issues, I always end up creating new project with new name, & copy everything.

Comment: Renaming it again doesn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed my problem by restoring the last version in which the project archived successfully (that was the last backup before renaming my project, so renaming probably caused the problem) and copied all my code from the new project to the old one.

Well, that isn't a nice and satisfactory solution, but at least it is working now.

> I really advise you against renaming your project, the whole trouble
>   you're getting in isn't worth it.